# "I wanna get wet in rain with you" Is there a better word than the vulgar-sounding "wet"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

From what I know [*drenched*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drench?q=drenched) is not the best word. I would like to say:

> I wanna get all wet (literally) with you in the rain.

Something that can express the feeling that I want to enjoy the rain in a place where it's just her, me, maybe on a beach, and it's raining (for some reason).

Comment: I would write something like "I want to run carefree through the rain with you."

Comment: (You might get  some inspiration from the song [Laughter in the Rain](http://www.metrolyrics.com/laughter-in-the-rain-lyrics-neil-sedaka.html).)

Comment: Well, I guess "vulgar-sounding" is in the ear of the hearer.  There are probably a myriad of words that can replace "wet" with more context as to what is meant to be accomplished by being in the rain.  Just standing in the rain together sounds like you don't have the sense to come in out of it so is supposed to be romantic?  time-stands-still?  child-like freedom?  a symbolic washing away of inhibitions?  I'd wanna know more! :-)

Comment: It'll be very hard to avoid any sexual or uretic connotation with anything to do with wetness. The best might to say it litterally: like in the  Pitbull song, (even though he's not using it literally) /www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/pitbull/rainoverme.html  "Let it rain over me"  ..Just use the word rain.

Comment: You don't need to use "wet" or any other adjective. Staying, walking, dancing  etc, in the rain already implies getting wet. Or, I like gettin soaked with you in the rain.

Comment: @P.Obertelli That song's all about sexual innuendo.

Comment: @nvz that's why I said, "Pitbull does not uses it litteraly". It is about sex effectively. But using rain instead of any other form of wetness related word is still what can be the least connoted. I should have used dancing in the rain as an example of non sexual wetness. (Unless I'm completely blind I cannot see any sexual or uretic connotation in this song.)  http://www.metrolyrics.com/dancing-in-the-rain-lyrics-shane-harper.html

Comment: I wanna get on a camel with you in the rain?

Comment: Camel+rain --> Wet camel toe? No innuendo at all...

Comment: "Let the rain wash over us," maybe?

Comment: You can make anything sound vulgar if you want to take it that way. There's nothing inherently vulgar-sounding in your proposed sentence any more than anything else you could say.

Comment: YouTube: [Dancing in the Rain - Singin' in the Rain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UmaFTEIZ84)

Comment: I think this is a charming sentiment and needs no euphemizing at all.

Comment: I can't understand why this question is, "On hold". There is absolutely nothing wrong with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanna get rained on with you

Comment: This isn't wrong, per se, but it sounds quite strange.

Comment: I like it. It's inventive and imaginative, and not hackneyed.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe "soaked," but I think that "drenched" is actually better.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe *I want to **just** stand in the rain with you.* The *just* emphasizes the value you place in the experience of being with the person you describe, no other motives intruding.

You could substitute other terms for *stand*, such as *soak*, *bask*, *wallow*, *play*, or any other non-sexual term.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason to say it like that is to refer to the innuendo. If you do anything in the rain, you will get wet so mentioning it is pointless unless it is an innuendo. That said, you could go with soaked as drenched feels negative. The word "soaked" isn't as likely to make someone's mind turn to the gutter. Though however you word it, the audience is going to make a difference. If they tend to fall into the gutter to begin with, there is no avoiding the reference with such a wording. However, if they are more... innocent minded, they may not even notice the reference with the obvious "wet".

You could also change it slightly. Maybe to run, walk, laugh, relax, sing, play (ok maybe not that one), etc... Then leave the rain there and it will imply that you are getting wet without having to say it. The idea is what picture it brings to your head. Simply mentioning rain, for most people, is enough to bring the wet picture you want.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph, but I don't think "soaked" is any better. If someone takes things like that, that's what they're going to hear. There's nothing wrong with "wet".

Comment: I was gonna say *doused* but it suffers the same possible entendre as drenched, soaked...

Comment: thanks for the reply. Really like the way how you put it.

Answer (score 1):

Being in the rain makes you wet. You don't need to point that out. Just say what you want to do in the rain, and the wet part follows:

> I'd like to sit/stand/walk/run/dance/sing in the rain with you.

But, what it sounds to me like what you're actually trying to say is

> I'd like to enjoy the rain with you.

I don't see anything wrong with "wet" personally. If someone is going to take everything you say sexually, that's just going to happen. Furthermore, when you say "I want to get wet with you" my mind goes to drugs, not sex, as "getting wet" means smoking crack. It might stick out in that sentence because it's unnecessary.